# Zend Route Regex and optional parameters

Tags: regex, zend-framework, router, routes

I want to use a URL like this:

site.com/car-list/param1/value1/param2/value2

"car" is variable and can be anytihng. i solved the "site.com/car-list" part like this:

```
    $categoryRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '(\b.+\-list\b)',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'search',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        array(
            1 => 'productType'
        )
    );
```

I can get "car-list" when i want "productType" param. But i cant get rest of the url with $this->_getParam() in controller.

how can i do this? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, i don't see how to make it with Router_Route_Regex, but with Router_Route it would be easier (thought, i replace "-" with "/")

```
$categoryRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
    ':car/list/*',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'search',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

magic happens due to the "/*" at the end of the string. :car variable can be got with $request->getParam('car');

Comment: i think i have to accept this because i already wasted 3 hours with Regex. Thanks.